# Highcharts create legend for waterwall and stack column chart

Tags: charts, highcharts

New to Highcharts, need to make a waterfall and stack column chart, as in attached image. I have completed the chart but unable to get the legend for the stack column.

https://jsfiddle.net/b9vLxoua/ `Here is the chart code`

[Required chart with legend highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2jKZ.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: Would you like to have a regular legend functionality to hide/show the points?

Comment: I would like to have the column stack legend only (3 colors), as highlighted in the attached image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom legend by using the SVERenderer tool on the render callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qhr6nsw9/

```
  render() {
    let chart = this,
                    colors = ['#003975', '#F9BD50', '#3FA27E']

    chart.series[1].points.forEach((p,i) => {
      if (p.category === 0) {
                    if (p.customRect) {
                        p.customRect.destroy();
                    }
        p.customRect = chart.renderer.rect(chart.plotSizeX + chart.plotLeft + 10, 100 + i * 50, 20, 20, 5)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[i],
            zIndex: 3
          })
          .add();
                    if (p.customText) {
                        p.customText.destroy();
                    }   
                    p.customText = chart.renderer.label(p.t, chart.plotSizeX + chart.plotLeft + 40, 100 + i * 50).add()
      }
    })
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render